# How does adaptively patterned variation explain the variety in specific personalities?

Tags: personality, evolutionary-psychology

I read the article "Evolutionary perspectives on personality dynamics" by Lukaszewski, which explains that differences in personality can be explained by **adaptively patterned variation**. But it doesn't explain for each of the specific personality traits of the Big 5 why one type is better in some environments and not in other environments. It only explains it for shame.
How can they be explained?

For extraversion I found an explanation why extraversion has advantages and disadvantages, but not how that would depend on the environment, so it doesn't answer why there is variation.

At first I though frequency dependent selection could answer this question, but I did not find anything on that, it only seems to explain the variation in "hawks" and "doves", and similar variations.